# How to get NSArray out of for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsarray

I cannot get the following code to work:

The .h code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * messages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) __block NSMutableArray *m1;
```

The .m code
    NSArray *messages;

```
NSString *posts;
NSArray* scoreArray;
@synthesize m1;


-(void)awakeFromNib {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];



[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

[query includeKey:@"message"];






[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            PFObject *post = object[@"body"];



            m1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




            posts = [object objectForKey:@"body"];
            [m1 addObject:posts];

            NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", posts);

             scoreArray = [query findObjects];

            NSLog(@"Array: %@", scoreArray);


            m1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [m1 addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            _messages = [m1 valueForKey:@"body"];




        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}];

NSLog(@"%@",[_messages objectAtIndex:0]);
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
```

The last NSLog reveals nothing... I think I am not declaring the variables correctly, but do not know how to fix it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: the last NSLog may run before your block passed to `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` even starts running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running code "in the background" there's no guarantee of ordering.

The call to schedule your background operation (*findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:*) will return to the caller immediately. After that, a moment later, your final *NSLog* will run.

The block passed to *findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:* will execute at some future time.

Comment: If you want something to happen on the main thread after your block finishes, add a `dispatch_sync()` call at the end of your async block to run another block on the main thread.